# Android download remote content

Tags: android, android-layout, http

I want to create Android app where I have items with images and descriptions - only for information, no interact. How can I download layout from server and show remote data? I'm newby - I can create simple apps, but this problem is not solved in Internet. I search in Google, Youtube but I can't find anything.

Comment: You cannot download a layout from server. You can load the data through some web service and then display it in your app. You can find countless  tutorials and resources on Google to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a layout in your app (you cannot parse layout from server only data can be parsed), then connect your layout items to loading data from server. 
You can check out an basic example to populate list view from server from [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-async-listview-jee-and-restful.html) and [here](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/)